# Deployment on Github Actions for all tags for Azure App Service

Tags: azure, github, github-actions

I have a code in Github and I use Github Actions to deployment so I use workflows/azure-container-webapp.yml. The beginning of the file is as follows:

YAML

```
name: Deploy on branch master
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

permissions:
      id-token: write
      contents: read
jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash
```

I have the following setting in App registrations -> Owned applications -> Certificates & secrets -> Federated credentials:

```
Entity type: Branch
GitHub branch name: master
```

And running any other branch in Github Actions gives an error.
I would like to run with tags, not branch name but I don't want to change the tag name every time in the App registrations settings (each new deployment is with a new tag). It would be best to set it for all tags.

I ran deployment with the tag but I got an error as in the attachment.